# How to add python file under python package on bitbake

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake, speed-test

I am trying to add a speedtest.py file under python (`import speedtest` in python prompt) on Bitbake system. I am not sure how to add this file in the recipe (or somewhere else) so that it will add under `/usr/lib/python/` directory.

Any pointer in this direction would be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use `speedtest.py` from Bitbake, or do you want it installed onto the target system?

Comment: I want to use it from bitbake. I finally created a recipe for it and add it into packagegroup.
I was trying to figure out any different way than recipe if you want to add single .py file into your system.